# Use the contents of .gitignore to get identical filtering with Java NIO PathMatcher

Tags: git, filter, nio

I am using FileSystem#getPathMatcher(glob-syntax).matches(...) to filter out files during copy.

I want the same filtering behaviour as git. Therefore I would like to reuse the glob-definitions in the .gitignore file.

So far I don't manage to get identical filtering to git.

```
public class GitignorePathMatcher {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path start = Paths.get("/home/carsten/project");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(start.resolve(".gitignore"));
        for (ListIterator<String> iterator = lines.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String line = iterator.next();
            String trim = line.trim();
            if (trim.length() == 0 || trim.contains("#")) iterator.remove();
            else iterator.set(trim);
        }

        print(lines);
        System.out.println();

        filter(lines, start);
    }

    private static void filter(List<String> filters, Path start) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fs = start.getFileSystem();

        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                boolean include = include(dir, filters);
                System.out.println((include ? "ADD " : "[SKIP] ") + dir);
                return include ? CONTINUE : SKIP_SUBTREE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                boolean include = include(file, filters);
                System.out.println((include ? "ADD \t" : "[SKIP] \t") + file);
                return CONTINUE;
            }

            boolean include(Path dir, List<String> filters) {
                for (String pattern : filters) {
                    if (fs.getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern).matches(dir)) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private static void print(List<String> lines) {
        for (String line : lines) System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just added the code. You can test against some Git project. You will see that it doesn't skip any files or folders :(

Comment: I am still tinkering. So far no luck. Is the Java PathMatcher glob-Syntax just not powerful enough to match Git's .gitignore?